# Starting with a quantum gate in quantikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, qcircuit, quantikz

I am trying to start a quantikz circuit with a gate extending over multiple wires to get a diagram like the following: [image]

This is made with the following quantikz code:

```
 \begin{quantikz}
     \gate[wires=4]{\ket{\psi_c}} & \qw \\
     &\qw \\
     & \qw \\
     & \qw
 \end{quantikz}
```

This throws a lot of error messages but it seems to do the job. However trying to do more complicated circuits with this method is not good since they start to render poorly. As an example take this next quantikz code:

```
\begin{quantikz}
     \gate[wires=4]{\bra{\psi_T}}&\qw  & \gate[wires=4]{\ket{\psi_c}} \\
     &\qw&\\
     &\qw&\\
     &\qw&
 \end{quantikz}
```

This renders in the following way:
[image]

Clearly this doesn't render properly; im not sure how to fix this problem and essentially start a quantikz circuit with a gate which then has wires going out of it.

Comment: Welcome. // Please make it a habit to post only code, which compiles after copy and paste: yours doesn't, unfortunately. // You will obtain more and much better answers from doing so ...